# How can I create a control with IPAddress properties that can be edited in the designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ip-address, designer

I'm creating a control with properties of type `System.Net.IPAddress`.  The designer shows these as read-only, and seems to be matching them up with resources.  Is there a way to make it so that the user can edit these properties in the designer properties window, rather than having to open up the resource editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - the answer is to fake it:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[DisplayName("IPAddress")]
public string IPAddressText
{
    get { return this.IPAddress.ToString(); }
    set { this.IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(value); }
}

[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public IPAddress IPAddress
{
    get;
    set;
}
```